# How to send the filteredArray obtained through predicates index position in Array through segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

I have two arrays ,one I have obtained as response from server the other one I have obtained by filtering the array using predicates.as follows:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Locally"];

    reviewdataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    reviewdataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    NSPredicate *tPredicate =

    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id== %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userId"]];

    filteredReviewdataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    filteredReviewdataArray = [[reviewdataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:tPredicate]mutableCopy];
}
```

The reviewdataArray returns following:

```
(

{
    Rating = 2;

    "user_id" = "F2266E5D-C709-42FB-AD98-B75873AC2FD1";

},

{
    Rating = 3;

    "user_id" = "F2266E5D-C709-42FB-AD98-B75873AC2FD1";

},

{   Rating = 4;


    "user_id" = "9fbec513-b598-4593-bed4-fe882f67eb2e";

},

{
   Rating = 1;

    "user_id" = "7wrs-513-42638-451-bed4-gd23sdgg231";

}

)
```

The filteredReviewdataArray returns following:

```
{   Rating = 4;


 "user_id" = "9fbec513-b598-4593-bed4-fe882f67eb2e";

}
```

Now ,I am displaying these dictionaries in filteredReviewdataArray on tableView and through segue I am sending the index position of the selected row like as follows:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"rating"]) {

        NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       TripViewController *tripController = [segue destinationViewController];
       tripController.load = FALSE;
       tripController.index = index;  
    } 

}
```

But this displays wrong data.I actually want to send the index position of filteredReviewdataArray item in reviewdataArray through segue.How this can be achieved?

Comment: when are you sending the selected data to the TripViewController?

Comment: Why are you sending the tableview's `index` instead of the data? It makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Take One class variable of Int type:

```
var selectedIndex : Int!

// Add below code to your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           //You exixting code......
           selectedIndex = indexPath.row; 
    }

//Update your prepareForSegue: delegate like:

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"rating"]) {
       TripViewController *tripController = [segue destinationViewController];
       tripController.load = FALSE;
       tripController.index = selectedIndex;  
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

previous answer seems correct but does not work.
If you have a regular TVCtl and TVCell, iOS will call "prepare" BEFORE didSelectRow, so it's wrong.

try it placing breakpoints:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```

As you can see the flow is different. (it will work only if you use custom cell)

to make sample works, do as follows:

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

```
if let selected = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
    let row = selected.row
}
```

}

and do not use didSelect.

Comment: I ma using custom cell...but then also it is not working due..to different flow(prepare for segue works first and then did select)....Can you please translate the method to be used in objective c?